# context detectConflictsForObject

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

In iOS Core Data, there is a method on `NSManagedObjectContext` `detectConflictsForObject:`

This method's documentation says:

> If on the next invocation of save: object has been modified in its persistent store, the save fails. This allows optimistic locking for unchanged objects. Conflict detection is always performed on changed or deleted objects.

I have a `[context save]` that throws exception regardless whether I use `detectConflictsForObject` or not.

I thought this method will help me to determine whether a call to `[context save]` will cause a crash or not.

The specific situation I have is like this.
I have contexts A is parent context of B. B is parent context of C.

Some `NSManagedObject` was deleted from B and after a while `[C save]` is about to get called. This causes `"could not fulfill a fault"` exception which I thought I could detect early using the method `detectConflictsForObject` and thus avoid crashing.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is described in this document ["Troubleshooting Core Data"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002320-SW10). I think that you try to retrieve an attribute or relationship from the object previously deleted in other context. To check object's existing you could use [existingObjectWithID:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/existingObjectWithID:error:) method of NSManagedObjectContext. If the object cannot be fetched, or does not exist, or cannot be faulted, it returns nil. For example:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithAttributesOfObject:(NSManagedObject *)object {
    if ([self.managedObjectContext existingObjectWithID:object.objectID error:nil])
        ; // you can do something with object
    else
        ; // object was deleted
}
```

Comment: `existingObjectWithID:error:` works fine when the object is first time evaluated on the context. If I evaluate an entity and its properties, and then delete this entity from a parent context while the entity remained in memory the entire time.
A call to `existingObjectWithID:error:` will return the "cached" version of the object and will not contact the parent context if it doesn't think it's necessary. 

It also has something to do with the `stalenessInterval` on the context.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This method could return a cached object. But it never returns a fault. So when you will try to access properties of managed object after this check it will not cause an exception.